# What headers do I send to cause a PHP script's output to be cached?

Tags: php, http-headers

I'm using a PHP script to serve images (stored outside of webroot) to visitors who have provided credentials allowing them access.

I'm sending the following headers: 'Content-Type', 'Last-Modified', 'Content-Length', 'Content-Disposition' (to set filename).

I incorporated code to check `$_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE']` and if appropriate, send a 'HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified' and quit. But in Firebug I notice that the response headers for the request include this:

```
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
```

and the image does appear to be downloading anew every time I view the page. This is unnecessary; it makes sense for the images to be cached by the client. But I don't know what extra headers I should send to make this happen. What headers do I need to send?

Edit: These are the header commands I ended up putting in the script:

```
header('Cache-Control: private, max-age=0, must-revalidate');
header('Expires: Sat, 1 Jan 2000 12:00:00 GMT');
header('Pragma:');
```

Comment: Have you already tried setting Cache-Control and Pragma from within your script? Because you can set these from PHP... Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981973/is-my-php-script-cache-public-friendly for a similar question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send the `Expires`, `Cache-Control` and `Pragma` headers yourself:

Expires uses RFC 1123 date, format, eg: `Expires: Thu, 03 Feb 2011 15:16:16 GMT`

For Cache-Control you can do: `Cache-Control: public, max-age: 3600`. The max-age is in seconds.

As for Pragma, you can disable the web server's default response of no-cache with:

```
header('Pragma: ');
```

PS. Many webservers also include a way for you to tell the webserver handle serving the file.

In lighttpd you can use the [x-sendfile](http://blog.lighttpd.net/articles/2006/07/02/x-sendfile) header. In Apache you can use [mod_xsendfile](https://tn123.org/mod_xsendfile/) if you have it installed to do the same. In nginx you can use the [X-Accel-Redirect](http://wiki.nginx.org/XSendfile) header. Serving static files is really the webserver's job, and these are very handy features that you can take advantage of, while still hiding your files from public docroot area. For other webservers you can fallback to handling sending the headers for caching yourself.

Comment: Reading up on the Cache-Control header, it sounds like "private" would be more appropriate for me - is this not so?

Comment: If one request might result in two different responses, yes, but since you're serving images I thought that's not the case. However if it is, then it should indeed be private.

Comment: A request might result in different responses depending on whether or not the client is a user who has presented the appropriate credentials to view the image.

Answer (score 3):

Are you using sessions? Those tend to send no-cache headers to force a fresh page load each time, or some other section/module of your site is sending them.

You can try to force a cache-control header with something like:

```
header("Cache-control: max-age=3600, must-revalidate");
```

Comment: You could also use the `Expires` header, however the official docs state: if a response includes a Cache-Control field with the max-age directive, that directive overrides the Expires field.

Comment: This appears to work: my browser appears to be caching the image. I noticed this in the response headers in Firebug, though: "Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT". How do you think this comes about, and is it something I should worry about?

Comment: Also, yes, I'm using sessions.

Comment: Could be a bad date conversion somewhere in something intended to do a 10 year cache, and is setting an absolute 10 year period, instead of a relative one. Hard to say. You'd have to check everything in your server (php AND apache) to see where the cache header's coming from.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `Expires` and `Last-Modified` as described in this post: [How to cache images generated by PHP](http://dtbaker.com.au/random-bits/how-to-cache-images-generated-by-php.html)